# Newlines in X Axis in Matplotlib Cause Undesired Window Resizing/Jumping/Flickering Behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, unix-timestamp

I am plotting dates and times on the x axis in matplotlib. Because I want to plot as many labels as possible, I am using newlines in the x labels like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, this has the side effect of resizing the matplotlib window when I hover over the graph since it tries to print the x value, which contains the newlines, at the bottom.
See this video here as a demonstration:

[YouTube Link to Video](https://youtu.be/TlzE1rB1J70), watch in full resolution.

It even causes the whole chart to flicker sometimes, which doesn't exactly make it fun to interact with. I don't want to get rid of the toolbar, but I just need it to not print the x point in the bottom right corner (which is what's causing the window to resize).

Any idea how I can keep the toolbar but avoid this jumping/flickering issue? My code is below:

```
import os
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import matplotlib.dates as md
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import time

for entry in os.scandir('estimated_finish_times'):
  if entry.name.endswith('.csv'):
    print(entry.name)
    df = pandas.read_csv(entry.path)
    df['lookahead_finish'] = df['polltime'] + df['lookahead_time']
    df['combined_rate_finish'] = df['polltime'] + df['combined_rate_time']
    
    xd = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) for ts in df['polltime']]
    x1 = md.date2num(xd)
    
    yd = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) for ts in df['lookahead_finish']]
    y1 = md.date2num(yd) # df['lookahead_finish']
    
    yd = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) for ts in df['combined_rate_finish']]
    y2 = md.date2num(yd) # df['lookahead_finish']
    
    fig, ax = mp.subplots(figsize=(22, 11))
    
    yfmt = md.DateFormatter('%b. %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%b. %d\n%I:%M\n%p\n%Y')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mp.MaxNLocator(20))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mp.MaxNLocator(20))
    
    mp.plot(x1, y1, linewidth=2, label='lookahead_finish', marker='.', alpha=0.5)
    mp.plot(x1, y2, linewidth=2, label='combined_rate_finish', marker='.', alpha=0.3)
    
    mp.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.11, 1.0), loc="upper right")
    mp.title(f'{entry.name} Estimated Finish Time')
    mp.grid()
    # fig.canvas.toolbar.pack_forget()
    mp.show()
```

Note that every column in the dataframe is just unix timestamps (a value such as `1665123089`, which is `dtype: int64`). Also, I'm on Windows 10, Python 3.8.2, and `matplotlib==3.2.1`.

Rather than hide the toolbar, which has been a suggested solution, I would still like the controls to be accessible if possible:

[image]

Comment: I think you want to hide the toolbar, which is showing the date strings. Try `mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'` before each call to `fig, ax = mp.subplots(figsize=(22, 11))`.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, the problem is that this also hides the controls (like the home button, the pan and zoom, etc.) I would still like those to be accessible if possible. I added this requirement to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to get rid of the toolbar, but I just need it to not print the x point in the bottom right corner (which is what's causing the window to resize).

You can monkeypatch `ax.format_coord` to display a differently formatted string for a given x, y value (or None as below).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.format_coord = lambda x, y : '' # don't display anything
plt.show()
```

If you want to modify the string of the original `ax.format_coord`, then you have to wrap the original function:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
old_function = ax.format_coord
ax.format_coord = lambda x, y: old_function(x, y) + "some random nonsense"
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks this helps, but I have another question for my own understanding. If I use the lambda just to print x and y (`ax.format_coord = lambda x, y : f'x: {x} y:{y}'`), I get this: https://i.imgur.com/rKTk5Lm.png. Why is it printing those floats rather than the formatted dates? For example, how would I simply remove the newlines instead (replace them with spaces)?

Comment: >Why is it printing those floats rather than the formatted dates? -- We just gutted the function that converts the float to a formatted datetime so why is that surprising behaviour?

Comment: Thank you for editing the post, I didn't understand how it was working originally. Now I see.  `old_function = ax.format_coord` followed by `ax.format_coord = lambda x, y: old_function(x, y).replace("\n", " ")` gets me what I'm after.